# Stacked bar plots from two different sources in Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I suppose this is fairly easy but I tried for a while to get an answer without much success. I want to produce a stacked bar plot for two categories but I have such information in two separate date frames:

This is the code:

```
first_babies = live[live.birthord == 1] # first dataframe
others = live[live.birthord != 1] # second dataframe

fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

first_babies.groupby(by=['prglength']).size().plot(
                     kind='bar', ax=ax1, label='first babies') # first plot
others.groupby(by=['prglength']).size().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1, color='r',
               label='others') #second plot
ax1.legend(loc='best')
ax1.set_xlabel('weeks')
ax1.set_ylabel('frequency')
ax1.set_title('Histogram')
```

[image]

But I want something like this or as I said, a stacked bar plot in order to better distinguish between categories:

[image]

I can't use `stacked=True` because it doesn't work using two different plots and I can't create a new dataframe because `first_babies` and `others`don't have the same number of elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new column to distinguish `'first_babies'`:

```
live['first_babies'] = live['birthord'].lambda(x: 'first_babies' if x==1 else 'others')
```

You can [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking) the groupby:

```
grouped = live.groupby(by=['prglength', 'first_babies']).size()
unstacked_count = grouped.size().unstack()
```

Now you can plot a [stacked bar-plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots) directly:

```
unstacked_count.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Comment: Interesting but I get the following error: ReshapeError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. That's true, what you put as week is actually 'prglength' and certainly has repeated values.

Comment: @RobertSmith This should do it!

Comment: By the way, I think the lambda won't work. I used map instead.